# Preserve structure of an HTML page, removing all text nodes

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to remove all text from html page that I load with nokogiri. For example, if a page has the following:

```
<body><script>var x = 10;</script><div>Hello</div><div><h1>Hi</h1></div></body>
```

I want to process it with Nokogiri and return html like the following after stripping the text like so:

```
<body><script>var x = 10;</script><div></div><div><h1></h1></div></body>
```

(That is, remove the actual h1 text, text between divs, text in p elements etc, but keep the tags. Also, don't remove text in the script tags.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
html = "<body><script>var x = 10;</script><div>Hello</div><div><h1>Hi</h1></div></body>"
hdoc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
hdoc.xpath( '//*[text()]' ).each do |el|
  el.content='' unless el.name=="script"
end

puts hdoc
#=> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
#=> <html><body>
#=> <script>var x = 10;</script><div></div>
#=> <div><h1></h1></div>
#=> </body></html>
```

**Warning**: As you did not specify how to handle a case like `<div>foo<h1>bar</h1></div>` the above may or may not do what you expect. Alternatively, the following may match your needs:

```
hdoc.xpath( '//text()' ).each do |el|
  el.remove unless el.parent.name=="script"
end
```

### Update

Here's a more elegant solution using a single xpath to select all text nodes not part of a `<script>` element. I've added more text nodes to show how it handles them.

```
require 'nokogiri'
hdoc = Nokogiri::HTML <<ENDHTML
  <body>
  <script>var x = 10;</script>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div>foo<h1>Hi</h1>bar</div>
  </body>
ENDHTML
hdoc.xpath( '//text()[not(parent::script)]' ).each{ |text| text.remove }
puts hdoc
#=> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
#=> <html><body>
#=> <script>var x = 10;</script><div></div>
#=> <div><h1></h1></div>
#=> </body></html>
```

For Ruby 1.9, the meat is more simply:

```
hdoc.xpath( '//text()[not(parent::script)]' ).each(&:remove)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. technically i would want the answer to be <div><h1></h1></div> otherwise i think the script tags inside divs would also get removed. i used a solution similar like so:

Comment: @user58948 I'm confused by your comment. As shown in the output of my first solution, and proven out by testing the second, both of my answers produce `<div><h1></h1></div>`.

Comment: @user58948 Regarding your pastebin, you can make the second part simpler via: `document.xpath("//script").each_with_index{ |elem,i| elem.content = a[i] }`; that way you don't need to explicitly track the index. Or: `document.xpath('//script').zip( a ).each{ |elem,old_content| elem.content=old_content }`.

Comment: @user58948 I've updated my answer with a simpler, better solution.